# Making lists based on values in column

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have an interesting case. In column `FID2` I have some values, based on each i'd like to create a list. The column `Ncircles` determines the list.
For example:

- If there's a value `0` in `Ncircles`, i'd like to create a list based on the value in `FID2` in the same row as `[i]`, where `i` is equal to `FID2`.
- If there's a value `1` in `Ncircles`, i'd like to create a list based on
  the value in `FID2` in the same row as `[i-1, i, i +1]`, where `i` is equal to `FID2`.
- If there's a value `3` in `Ncircles`, i'd like to create a list based on 
  the value in `FID2` in the same row as `[i-3, i-2, i -1 i, i+1, i+2, i +3]`, where `i` is equal to `FID2`.

This is an example of df:

```
          FID2  Ncircles
0        50141         0
1        56188         1
2        75035         0
3        94937         3
```

The final lists can be written all in the same, one list. Do you have any suggestions how to do this?

An expected output would be a new list:

```
Newlist = [50141, 56187, 56188, 56188, 75035, 94934, 94935, 94936, 94937, 94938, 94939, 94940]
```

Comment: provide expected output

Comment: Is performance important?

Comment: If you mean the time, then no. It is not. Your solution is great, but if fails me for `[i-2490,i-2489,i-2488,i-1,i+1,i+2488,i+2489,i+2490]` cases

Comment: `but if fails me` - You mean get negative numbers?

Comment: No. The range function does not work. I combined the solution with a pre-defined function and `if` command and it works!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `range` in list comprehension with flattening:

```
Newlist = [c for a, b in zip(df['FID2'], df['Ncircles']) for c in range(a-b, a+b+1)]
print (Newlist)
[50141, 56187, 56188, 56189, 75035, 94934, 94935, 94936, 94937, 94938, 94939, 94940]
```

Answer (score 3):

An approach using apply:

```
def create_list(ncircles, fid2):
    return [fid2 + k for k in range(-ncircles, ncircles+1)]

df['fid2list'] = df.apply(axis=1, func=lambda l: create_list(l.Ncircles, l.FID2))

    FID2  Ncircles                                           fid2list
0  50141         0                                            [50141]
1  56188         1                              [56187, 56188, 56189]
2  75035         0                                            [75035]
3  94937         3  [94934, 94935, 94936, 94937, 94938, 94939, 94940]
```

And the lists can be combined with `np.concatenate(df['fid2list'].values)`:

```
array([50141, 56187, 56188, 56189, 75035, 94934, 94935, 94936, 94937,
   94938, 94939, 94940])
```

Comment: This works great! But it fails for me, if i have a condition e.g. `[i-2490,i-2489,i-2488,i-1,i+1,i+2488,i+2489,i+2490]` since i cannot put this in a `range` function. Can you please make a suggestion how to approach this?

Comment: @energyMax I don't quite understand the logic/pattern in `[i-2490,i-2489,i-2488,i-1,i+1,i+2488,i+2489,i+2490]`. Omitting the `i-1` and `i+1` part, it would be as simple as `return [fid2 - (2487 - k) for k in range(-ncircles, ncircles+1)]` (or something similar) . What's the value of `ncircles` in that example?

Comment: If I may, in case i have a list `[(50141, 56187, 56188, 56189), 75035, 94934, 94935]`, how can I extract values in a single `list` without `()`?

Comment: @energyMax Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2158395/flatten-an-irregular-list-of-lists